# How can light travel the distance of nuclear size in negative time?

Tags: time, half-life

at first i thought time cannot be negative or zero but after going through the statement
*"time taken by light to cross a distance of nuclear size is 10^-23"* iam confused

[image]

Comment: It looks like you copied that table from the Tamilnadu Board Class 11 Physics text book, Chapter 1. Please do not copy material without giving its source!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the plagiarism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't negative times, those are standard notation for [exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

For example, $10^{-1} = \frac{1}{10} = 0.1; 10^{-3} = \frac{1}{10^{3}} = 0.001$, etc.